# Qt Sqlite error 1 - table already exists

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

I have a problem with Qt and sqlite. Until recently, I didn't have any problems creating tables, but now, whenever I try to create a table (using the exact same function) I get an error message:

```
QSqlError("1", "Unable to fetch row", "table selections already exists")
```

My query strings are as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE external_files (path VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL, used INTEGER (12) NOT NULL);
```

This is the same as before too.

The strange thing is though, all the tables are created without a problem, but I still get error messages.

If you have any ideas why this happens, I would appreciate it. :)

**UPDATE: Minimal, complete, verifiable example:**

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QSqlDatabase>
#include <QSqlQuery>
#include <QSqlError>
#include <QFile>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE", "CONN");
    db.setDatabaseName("test.db");
    if(!db.open()){
        qDebug() << "Connection failed!";
    }

    QFile tableListFile(":/resources/sql/tables.sql");
    if(tableListFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    {
        QTextStream stream(&tableListFile);
        while(!stream.atEnd())
        {
            QString queryString = stream.readLine();
            qDebug() << "Query string: " << queryString;
            QSqlQuery query(queryString, db);
            if(!query.exec()){
                qDebug() << "Query error: " << query.lastError();
            }
        }
    }

    db.close();

   return a.exec();
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The database tells you "table `selections` already exists", and then you wonder why the table is there?

Comment: The database is empty before I run this. It creates the table selections but i get this error message anyway.

Comment: Obviously, the database is *not* empty before the CREATE TABLE statement.

Comment: Well.. Ok, but it should be, my db file doesn't even exist before my CreateProject function call, in which i call this function..
E: Could the way I connect to the db be the problem's source?

Comment: Are you absolutely positive there is no way the `CreateProject` calls `CreateDatabase` twice? Are you perfectly sure that you're deleting the DB file on program exit (or before the next call to `CreateProject`)? Have you checked for copy/paste errors with other table creation calls? It's all a bit poking around without context...

Comment: I'm pretty sure.. It's called once.
CreateProject function added.

Comment: There's no magic to this. You're doing something wrong. Put all the relevant code (and no other code!) into a single `main.cpp` file, include the SQL program as a string, minimize, and see what you get. So far, the code you show is OK, except that we have to guess as to what all the not-shown code might be doing.

Comment: In other words: you need to create a [mcve].

Comment: Updated. Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example added. You are right, it's better like that, sorry for the wait.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I managed to solve the problem.
The query was executed 2 times for each query string, and that caused the error messages.
To get to the solution, i edited my code like this:

```
QString queryString = stream.readLine();
qDebug() << "Query string: " << queryString;
QSqlQuery query;
if(!query.exec(queryString)){
    qDebug() << "Query error: " << query.lastError();
}
```

Comment: I have made the same mistake. It is not easily guessable that query is executed by simply creating the QSqlQuery object.